# Capture barcode scan when minimized

Tags: vb.net, barcode

I'm dealing with a barcode scanner that acts as a keyboard emulation.
I print my barcode labels with a custom heading character (pipe) .
In my main form, I listen to the keypress event and as soon as I see the custom header character, I start receiving the scan and than do my stuffs.

This method works pretty well if my application is focused but can't do nothing if the application is minimized or unfocused.

I tried to setup a keyboard hotkey. It partialli works: my application get focused on the first character but is not fast enought to capture the subsequent characters spitted very fast from the scanner.

Any idea on how to capture this keystrokes with the application unfocused?
Obviously if the heading char id detected the subsequent characters must be suppressed until the sequence is completed with a vbcr or a timeout is reached.

Note that the scanner spits a sequence of 15 characters in less than a tenth of a second

Comment: I think you will need to use a [low level keyboard hook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Windows works, only the active application will handle keyboard input.  Thus, when your application is minimized, it will not receive or handle any keyboard input.

As Bradley Uffner commented, you need a global keyboard handler, I've used this in the past and it works quite well.  Basically a system wide listener that will handle keyboard input even while minimized.